# Sonata Media Bundle - How to get Image or Gallery by Id

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

Is it possible to get an image or gallery from Sonata Media Bundle by Id?

I know how to get an image or gallery which is related to an entity. But in this case I just want to get an image or gallery without an entity.

Something like:

```
$media = $mediaProvider->getMediaById(12);
```

or

```
$gallery = $mediaProvider->getGalleryById(2);
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

In the controller get the gallery:

```
$galleryId = 3;
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ApplicationSonataMediaBundle:Gallery');
$gallery = $repo->find($galleryId);
$gallery = $gallery->getGalleryHasMedias();
```

And in the twig template:

```
{% for img in gallery %}
    {% media img.media, 'gallery' %}
{% endfor %}
```